# Как сделать текст жирным в WPF TextBox в моем примере?

Tags: c#

У меня есть свойство в модели

```
...
        public string LastClipFrame
        {
            get
            {
                var result = MCConstants.DEFAULT;

                if (_LastClipFrame != MCConstants.DEFAULT_LAST_CLIP_FRAME)
                {
                    return _LastClipFrame.ToString();
                }
                else if (IsLastFrameClipInFocus)
                {
                    result = string.Empty;
                    IsLastFrameClipInFocus = false;
                }

                return result;
            }

            set
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                {
                    _LastClipFrame = MCConstants.DEFAULT_LAST_CLIP_FRAME;
                }
                else if (!value.Contains("-") && int.TryParse(value, out int tmpVal))
                {
                    _LastClipFrame = tmpVal;
                }

                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

...
```

и я его использую в `.xalm`

```
...
                                           <TextBox x:Name="Tb_last_clip_frame"
                                                        Grid.Column="0"
                                                         GotFocus="Tb_last_clip_frame_GotFocus"
                                                         LostFocus="Tb_last_clip_frame_LostFocus"
                                                        Text="{Binding Path=LastClipFrame, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                                        Margin="5,5,0,5" 
                                                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />


...
```

Теперь я хочу добавить условие, что если `LastClipFrame = "default"`, то ничего не делай, но если любое другое значение, то пиши его жирным. Я нашел много разных примеров, как сделать текс цветным, как жирным через слово или через букву, но ничего о том, как просто сделать проверку условия и установить жирным текст, типо как `textBox.setBold(true)`

Как это сделать?

Comment: Просто сделайте триггер (`<Trigger Property="Text" Value="default">`).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ а можно пример? Никогда не работал с тригерами...

Comment: Ну допустим [так](https://pastebin.com/FPiBhkdR).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ да, но так получается, что он выделяет жирным если находит `default` , а мне как раз нужно, чтоб он выделял жирным любое слово кроме `default`

Comment: Ну делайте обратное. Установите изначально жирный текст, а если `== "default"` - делаете текст обычным (на подобие [этого](https://pastebin.com/DhtMM1W7)).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ оо, спасибо! Это то, что нужно. Можете опубликовать, я отмечу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения данной задачи достаточно всего одного триггера в стиле:

Если текст у `TextBox` будет равен `default`, то текст станет жирным:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Text" Value="default">
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

[image: result 1]

Если нам нужно обратное, что бы текст был жирным только тогда, когда он не равен `default`, то устанавливаем по умолчанию жирный, а триггером меняем на обычный:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Text" Value="default">
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

[image: result 2]

Как видите, XAML позволяет многое, так что удачи в его изучении!